# How to project an Android phone to projector in real time?

Tags: android, projector

I want to project the screen of my phone using a projector. So far, I've seen some who did it by installing an application on their PC to get a live view of the phone's screen and then connecting the PC to a projector.

Now, I am wondering if I can connect my phone directly to the projector? Of course, that is assuming that I have a micro USB to VGA adapter. Is this possible? What application do I need to let my phone communicate to a projector? How do I do this?

Comment: While interesting, this is Off Topic (it's an end-user question, not a developer question). Now, if the question was about asking what API could be used...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard on external displaying for android, yet. Many today's model support HDMI, for some platform, system just mirror the phone screen onto projector (like Toshiba), some provides vendor specific API to control displaying (like Moto), some simply cannot control so far (like HTC).

Comment: If there is no standard for this yet, do you know any application which could be of use?

Comment: For Moto platform, there is an app named Real HDMI. For HTC EVO, there is HDMIWin or FullHDMI.

Comment: Thank you! I think Samsung also has their own HDMI adapter.