# Android: Controlling an External Monitor (e.g., Projector)

Tags: android, projector, external-display

I'm looking for a way to use an android tablet to control an external screen. More specifically, I'd like my app to display one view on the tablet, and a second on an external device, such as a projector. I've yet to come across a way of doing this in my reading, but I'm not sure if I'm asking the right questions. Is such a thing possible? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8556889/1286571) seems to suggest it might be, at least for certain hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late...but now there is an answer.

So far some vendor specific..and I think 'private' apis were there to do that.
But from API level 17, android officially supports external display feature.

You can use the "android android.app.Presentation" class from API level 17 to achieve this.

Please see the below links for more details.
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html

Comment: That looks like exactly what I want. Thanks!